# Three.js texture is not loading - what would cause this?

Tags: javascript, 3d

I am trying to create a scene using .obj and .mtl files exported from blender. The object is literally just a rectangle (it needs to be a .obj file. more objects will be added to create a scene) I am able to see the material load, but cannot see the texture being applied in chrome or firefox.

[the mtl file text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iyr4t.png)

[the obj file text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUM8M.png)

Here is the javascript code:

```js
const obj_loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(),
      mtl_loader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
   
// uses example of OBJ + MTL from three.js/examples
mtl_loader
.setTexturePath('bar/')
.setPath('bar/')
.load('floor.mtl', (materials) => {

  materials.preload()

  obj_loader
  .setMaterials(materials)
  setPath('bar/')
  .load('floor.obj', (object) => {
  
    // everything returns status 200!
    // material is being applied but no texture
    scene.add(object);
  
  })
});
```

[project file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKw4K.png)

Checking the console, requests for the mtl, obj, and image files are returning 200 status codes

[but the model renders without texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQdd2.png)

No errors are in the console at all. What would cause this issue in Three.js? I suspect something is wrong with the .obj or .mtl but I cannot find the problem. (the file paths are correct based on the logged ajax request).

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to the `.preload()` method not being called on the `materials` object returned in the material load callback. The `preload()` method basically creates the material objects loaded by the `MTLLoader`.

Consider the following updates, with this method call added:

```
const mtl_loader = new THREE.MTLLoader();    
mtl_loader.setTexturePath('bar/');
mtl_loader.setPath('bar/');
mtl_loader.load('floor.mtl', function(materials) {

  // Add this (see link below for more detail)
  materials.preload()

  const obj_loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
  obj_loader.setMaterials(materials);
  obj_loader.setPath('bar/');
  obj_loader.load('floor.obj', function(object) {

    scene.add(object);  
  })
});
```

[Here is a link](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/c570b9bd95cf94829715b2cd3a8b128e37768a9c/examples/js/loaders/MTLLoader.js#L305) to the THREE source code which shows the inner workings of `.preload()` - hope this helps!

Comment: I had copied the code manually because copy/paste wasn't playing well with my terminal (and missed that line in OP, but it was a part of the original source). It turns out it was an issue with the model exported by Blender. I will update my question to show what went wrong

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be an issue with the UV mapping of the texture. In Blender, you can create a texture, and Blender will show the texture in 'render' mode, even if the UV map is not set (It will wrap automatically).

[Blender showing render, even without UV Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YezEq.png)

This was especially frustrating because I had these settings when exporting the file:

[export settings for OBJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVB6s.png)

The MTL and OBJ file appeared to have all the content in it, but by manually UV mapping the texture (instead of using a simple repeat in the "texture" menu) the issue was resolved when I exported again.

[UV/Image editor needed to be used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmeEl.png)

Sorry for any confusion that may have caused. I hope it helps anyone who has the same issue exporting from Blender.